# Terminal not running scripts with jruby

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, jruby, sikuli-x

This is my first time using both JRuby and VS Code. I'm working on a project for an internship and had opened the folder for the cloned repo in VS Code. I was able to run the Ruby scripts that were already present with no problem yesterday, but now when I try to run them from the terminal (the same way I was doing before), the terminal will pause for a second and then print the path again as if it had finished successfully, except nothing's happened. I've put print statements on the first line of the scripts, and they don't even print. It's like the scripts aren't even being run, except there's no error or anything to tell me WHY it's not being run. It's just Ruby -- I ran some python code to see if everything was wonky, but the python ran without a problem. I have no idea why this is happening!

Here's what it looks like on the terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\sjrob\Internship\client-automation> jruby Test.rb
PS C:\Users\sjrob\Internship\client-automation>
```

Here's Test.rb:

```
require 'java'
require './Lib/sikulixapi-2.0.4.jar'
java_import java.lang.System
java_import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed
java_import org.sikuli.script.Pattern
java_import org.sikuli.script.Screen
java_import org.sikuli.script.Location

puts "Hello from ruby"
```

I also tried commenting out the require/import statements so it's literally just `puts "Hello from ruby"` and still nothing. I don't even know where to start to fix this.

Comment: Does `jruby -e "puts 'testing'"  work?

Comment: Does `jruby --version` work?

Comment: jruby --version output: `jruby 9.2.11.1 (2.5.7) 2020-03-25 b1f55b1a40 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 10.0.2+13 on 10.0.2+13 +jit [mswin32-x86_64]`

Comment: jruby -e "puts 'testing'" output: `2020-05-28T11:22:05.023-06:00 [main] WARN FilenoUtil : Native subprocess control requires open access to sun.nio.ch
Pass '--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=org.jruby.dist' or '=org.jruby.core' to enable.
testing`

Comment: So yes both work -- I'm going to try running VSCode again to see if anything's changed.

Comment: So for the next try, you just put the `puts 'testing'` into a rb file and invoke it via this file, and then you add the other lines of your original script one by one, until the problem shows up again. Then you know at lest which line is responsible.